# OpenGL ES 2.0 Convert int[] to GLubyte[]

Tags: opengl-es

The following works as a texture...

```
GLubyte bytePix[4 * 3] ={
  255, 0, 0, //red
  0, 255, 0, //green
  0, 0, 255,  //blue
  255, 255, 0  //yellow
};
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pbytePix);
```

Problem is I am passing in my BMP as an int[] so I would need something more like this...

```
int bytePix[4 * 3] ={
      255, 0, 0, //red
      0, 255, 0, //green
      0, 0, 255,  //blue
      255, 255, 0  //yellow
};
```

But this doesn't show the same result.

My question is how do I convert the latter into a GLubtye[] or some other recognizable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your platform, `sizeof(int)` clearly isn't equal to `sizeof(GLubyte)`. I guess the immediate question is — why are you using `int`? It's likely just to be a huge waste of space if you're storing only values in the range 0–255.

You can't just use `GL_INT` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` in place of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, even if they are the same size as your `int` as you're using only a byte's range within each integer.

That aside, you'll notice that `glTexImage2D` doesn't have a `stride` parameter unlike `glVertexAttribPointer` and most of the other functions that exist primarily to provide data. So even though you have your values within bytes and those bytes are a predictable space apart, OpenGL can't pull them apart and repack them for you.

So the easiest option is to do it yourself:

```
void glTexImage2DWithStride(..., GLsizei stride, ...)
{
    // the following is written to assume GL_RGB; adapt as necessary
    GLubyte *byteBuffer = (GLubyte *)malloc(width * height * 3);

    for(int c = 0; c < width * height * 3; c++)
        byteBuffer[c] = originalBuffer[c];

    glTexImage2D(..., byteBuffer, ...);

    free(byteBuffer);
}
```

Failing that, supposing your `int` is four times as large as a byte, you could upload the original as an RGBA texture that's four times as large as its real size, then shrink it down in a shader, combining the `.r` or `.a`s (as per your endianness) into the correct output channels.

Comment: It is a good question, I am using int because I can't figure out how to access bmps within both Android and iOS easily so I decided to read in using the device and pass the pixel data to the native (OpenGL) side. We could take this offline if you feel like http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31290/loading-pixel-data-across-mobile-platforms

Comment: ;-)jni/src/game-gl.c:382:5: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
jni/src/game-gl.c:382:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/testand/src/game-gl.o] Error 1

Comment: Wow man worked like a charm the only problem the translations cause it to be flipped and mirrored gotta figure that one out

Comment: Flipped may just be the difference between OpenGL and paint programs; OpenGL considers (0, 0) to be the bottom left corner of the screen — like graph paper.

Comment: +Tommy Yeah I flipped the order in the texture cords

Answer (score 1):

Since ubyte and int are different in size, I guess you have to create a new ubyte array and convert explicitly element by element with a for loop, before passing it to OpenGL.